# Android: Fatal exception for switch case

Tags: android, fatal-error, switch-statement

I  added a switch case above the register() method  and I am getting Fatal exception and If i remove the switch case  its working fine. If I go for onclicklistner inside the register method its also working for me but I want to implement the switch case, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance...!

this is my code.

```
Thread t;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait while connecting...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
}


        Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
}


        String gender; 
    Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
      Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
         // Here in the above line I m getting the error//
      public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.regmalebtn:

          gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
            gender.equals("M");
        //  request.addProperty("gender",gender );

               break;

          case R.id.regfemalebtn: 

             gender = regfemalebtn.getText().toString();
                gender.equals("F");
            //  request.addProperty("gender", gender);
               break;
          default:
              break;

          }
          } 


public void register() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");


      EditText etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetfirstname);
      EditText etxt_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetlastname);
      EditText etxt_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetdob); 
             // in the above line i m getting error//
      EditText etxt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetemail); 
      EditText  etxt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetpwd);
      EditText  etxt_confirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetrepwd);
      EditText  etxt_mobno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetmobno);
          Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
                 // in the above line I m getting the error//
       Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
    //  String deviceid = null;
      String fname = etxt_user.getText().toString();
      String lname = etxt_pass.getText().toString();
      String dob = etxt_dob.getText().toString(); 
      String contact = etxt_mobno.getText().toString();


      String password;
      String confirmpassword ;
      String email =  etxt_email.getText().toString(); 
      password =  etxt_password.getText().toString(); 
      confirmpassword =  etxt_confirmpassword.getText().toString();



     final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12); 
                // in the above line I m getting errors//      
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
       soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              // in the above line i m getting error
       HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

these r my logcat messages

```
 06-21 18:59:34.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-21 18:59:34.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.soap/com.soap.Register}:  
   java.lang.NullPointerException
              06-21 18:59:34.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164):     
     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
            ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1164): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

Comment: Actually there is a NullPointerException in your code. Try initializing variable called gender before using it. something like this. String gender = null or "";.

Comment: @Varundroid Hi, did the same wat u have said but this time the errors r like this  06-21 19:12:51.885: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.soap/com.soap.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 19:12:51.885: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: What is `gender.equals("M");` supposed to do?  It will return a boolean without changing anything.  String assignment is `gender = "M";`.

Comment: @Haphazard Hi,the value of string variable equals to male and I need to post  it to server

Comment: Right, but that statement does nothing when it floats like that.  There is no assignment or condition based on that call.  You can remove it and your code will do the same thing.

Comment: @Haphazard Ya by removing the line I got the same error but How can we fix it?

Comment: I have no clue - you didn't post the line of the stack-trace where your code fails.  Once you post that and tell us what the line is in your code, I may be able to help.

Comment: @Haphazard Thank u for ur suggestion these r the corresponding code lines and the  messages in logcat                     
 Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
EditText etxt_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetdob); 
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

 at com.soap.Register.<init>(Register.java:66)

Comment: Please edit your original post with the full stack trace and add a //comment to your code on the line that is failing.

Comment: @Haphazard  Ya I did the same wat u said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regmalebtn` or `regfemalebtn` are likely null. Make sure `setContentView` in your activity is called before the `findViewById()` calls. Otherwise, they'll return null.

Comment: Thank u for the response, with in the main function only i added everything I mean entire code is inside main(). could you help me with the code?

Comment: @Raghu, I don't see the call to setContentView?

Comment: Lots of issues with your code. Not sure where to start. What method is `findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);` in?

Comment: Hi, regmalebtn and regfemalebtn are two buttons such that if we press first one we should pass value M(male) to server and female  for the second button, I am dealing with web-services and I want to pass the  user credentials to server  to parse them